# The same name for different models in different Django applications

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I have application 1 and application 2 in a Django project. I need each application to have its own table named Task and File. And the File table in each app refers ForeignKey to the Task table in its own app. It looks like this:

**app1.models**

```
class Task(BasicTask):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class File(BasicFile):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Task_one')
```

**app2.models**

```
class Task(BasicTask):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class File(BasicFile):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Task_two')
```

**main.models**

```
class BasicTask(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.name}"


class BasicFile(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    content = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.unique_id}"
```

The problem is that I get the following errors when I make migrations:

```
ERRORS:
app2.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
app2.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse query name for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
app1.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
app1.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse query name for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
```

Can you please tell me how to correct these errors?

Comment: although you are making model in different apps but it will save in the single database (may be)

Comment: @sunilghimire Tables are stored in the database with the prefix of the application name. For example: app1_task, app2_task, etc.

Comment: You may fix it changing the name of the imports using "as". 

Example:


applicantion 1: from app1.models import MyModel  -----                  
applicantion 2: from app1.models import MyModel as YourModel

Comment: @EliasPrado I am aware of this possibility, but it is not what I need in this case.

Comment: Have you tried using a polimorphic model? It may help you with what you are trying to do. However, all the data will be placed there.

Comment: @EliasPrado Thanks. I haven't tried using polymorphic model. I will explore this possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django show you the errors and say:

`Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for ...`

So you need to go to the models.fields:

1. `app2.Task.basictask_ptr`
2. `app1.Task.basictask_ptr`

and add/change `related_name` for the fields `basictask_ptr` for both models to the different values.

More about related fields is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't have done it without your help

Answer (score 0):

As a result, in order to fix this error, it was necessary to do this:

**app1.models**

```
class Task(BasicTask):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    basictask_ptr = models.OneToOneField(BasicTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app1', parent_link=True)

class File(BasicFile):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    basicfile_ptr = models.OneToOneField(BasicFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app1', parent_link=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**app2.models**

```
class Task(BasicTask):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    basictask_ptr = models.OneToOneField(BasicTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app2', parent_link=True)

class File(BasicFile):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    basicfile_ptr = models.OneToOneField(BasicFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='app2', parent_link=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**main.models**

```
class BasicTask(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.name}"


class BasicFile(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    content = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.unique_id}"
```